# Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 17 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am getting an error while executing below query. Please help me on this.

```
SELECT
    row_Date AS row_date,
    ForecastTimeGroup AS LastIntervalStartTime,
    DATEADD(ss,1799,ForecastTimeGroup) AS LastIntervalEndTime,
    DATEDIFF(mi,'01jan1900 00:00:00',DATEADD(ss,1799,ForecastTimeGroup)) AS    IntervalDurationMins,
        ReportCampaignID,
        ReportCampaignName,
    acd AS acd,
    rsv_level AS rsv_level,
SUM(abncalls) AS abncalls,
SUM(abntime) AS abntime,
SUM(acd_release) AS acd_release,
SUM(acdauxoutcalls) AS acdauxoutcalls,
SUM(acdcalls) AS acdcalls,
SUM(acdcalls_r1) AS acdcalls_r1,
SUM(acdcalls_r2) AS acdcalls_r2,
SUM(acdtime) AS acdtime,
SUM(acwincalls) AS acwincalls,
SUM(acwintime) AS acwintime,
SUM(acwoutadjcalls) AS acwoutadjcalls,
SUM(acwoutcalls) AS acwoutcalls,
SUM(acwoutoffcalls) AS acwoutoffcalls,
SUM(acwoutofftime) AS acwoutofftime,
SUM(acwouttime) AS acwouttime,
SUM(acwtime) AS acwtime,
SUM(ansringtime) AS ansringtime,
SUM(assists) AS assists,
SUM(auxincalls) AS auxincalls,
SUM(auxintime) AS auxintime,
SUM(auxoutadjcalls) AS auxoutadjcalls,
SUM(auxoutcalls) AS auxoutcalls,
SUM(auxoutoffcalls) AS auxoutoffcalls,
SUM(auxoutofftime) AS auxoutofftime,
SUM(auxouttime) AS auxouttime,
SUM(conference) AS conference,
SUM(da_abncalls) AS da_abncalls,
SUM(da_abntime) AS da_abntime,
SUM(da_acdcalls) AS da_acdcalls,
SUM(da_acdtime) AS da_acdtime,
SUM(da_acwincalls) AS da_acwincalls,
SUM(da_acwintime) AS da_acwintime,
SUM(da_acwoadjcalls) AS da_acwoadjcalls,
SUM(da_acwocalls) AS da_acwocalls,
SUM(da_acwooffcalls) AS da_acwooffcalls,
SUM(da_acwoofftime) AS da_acwoofftime,
SUM(da_acwotime) AS da_acwotime,
SUM(da_acwtime) AS da_acwtime,
SUM(da_anstime) AS da_anstime,
SUM(da_othercalls) AS da_othercalls,
SUM(da_othertime) AS da_othertime,
SUM(da_release) AS da_release,
SUM(event1) AS event1,
SUM(event2) AS event2,
SUM(event3) AS event3,
SUM(event4) AS event4,
SUM(event5) AS event5,
SUM(event6) AS event6,
SUM(event7) AS event7,
SUM(event8) AS event8,
SUM(event9) AS event9,
SUM(holdabncalls) AS holdabncalls,
SUM(holdacdtime) AS holdacdtime,
SUM(holdcalls) AS holdcalls,
SUM(holdtime) AS holdtime,
SUM(i_acdaux_outtime) AS i_acdaux_outtime,
SUM(i_acdauxintime) AS i_acdauxintime,
SUM(i_acdothertime) AS i_acdothertime,
SUM(i_acdtime) AS i_acdtime,
SUM(i_acwintime) AS i_acwintime,
SUM(i_acwouttime) AS i_acwouttime,
SUM(i_acwtime) AS i_acwtime,
SUM(i_auxintime) AS i_auxintime,
SUM(i_auxouttime) AS i_auxouttime,
SUM(i_auxstbytime) AS i_auxstbytime,
SUM(i_auxtime) AS i_auxtime,
SUM(i_availtime) AS i_availtime,
SUM(i_da_acdtime) AS i_da_acdtime,
SUM(i_da_acwtime) AS i_da_acwtime,
SUM(i_otherstbytime) AS i_otherstbytime,
SUM(i_othertime) AS i_othertime,
SUM(i_ringtime) AS i_ringtime,
SUM(i_stafftime) AS i_stafftime,
SUM(incomplete) AS incomplete,
SUM(noansredir) AS noansredir,
SUM(o_acdcalls) AS o_acdcalls,
SUM(o_acdtime) AS o_acdtime,
SUM(o_acwtime) AS o_acwtime,
SUM(phantomabns) AS phantomabns,
SUM(ringcalls) AS ringcalls,
SUM(ringtime) AS ringtime,
SUM(ti_auxtime) AS ti_auxtime,
SUM(ti_auxtime0) AS ti_auxtime0,
SUM(ti_auxtime1) AS ti_auxtime1,
SUM(ti_auxtime2) AS ti_auxtime2,
SUM(ti_auxtime3) AS ti_auxtime3,
SUM(ti_auxtime4) AS ti_auxtime4,
SUM(ti_auxtime5) AS ti_auxtime5,
SUM(ti_auxtime6) AS ti_auxtime6,
SUM(ti_auxtime7) AS ti_auxtime7,
SUM(ti_auxtime8) AS ti_auxtime8,
SUM(ti_auxtime9) AS ti_auxtime9,
SUM(ti_availtime) AS ti_availtime,
SUM(ti_othertime) AS ti_othertime,
SUM(ti_stafftime) AS ti_stafftime,
SUM(transferred) AS transferred,

    MAX(MartLoadID) AS MartLoadID
FROM VF_ATT_Mart.mart.IPThAgentIntraday_ReportCampaign_30mins ipt
```

Comment: I can't read that wall of code.

Comment: Even with code formatting its still difficult - Can you do some basic work of removing some columns and narrowing it down to which field is causing it?

Comment: You should start by adding a `group by` clause

Comment: SELECT
    row_Date AS row_date,
    ForecastTimeGroup AS LastIntervalStartTime,
    DATEADD(ss,1799,ForecastTimeGroup) AS LastIntervalEndTime,
    DATEDIFF(mi,'01jan1900 00:00:00',DATEADD(ss,1799,ForecastTimeGroup)) AS    IntervalDurationMins,
        ReportCampaignID,
        ReportCampaignName,
    acd AS acd,
    rsv_level AS rsv_level

FROM VF_ATT_Mart.mart.IPThAgentIntraday_ReportCampaign_30mins ipt

Comment: Your last comment is just code, what do you mean?